# How to Convert String with Removed Leading 0 to Date

Tags: java

2016-12-12 23:59:52 gets converted to "Mon Dec 12 23:59:52 CST 2016" correctly

but the following does not

2016-12-13 0:31:13 gets wrongly converted to "Thu Jan 12 00:31:13 CST 2017"

Here is my formater

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");
```

There is a missing leading 0 in my hour, which cause the converting error. How to make the formater compatible to the time with removed leading 0s such as **2016-1-1 0:0:0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No converting error and has nothing to do with missing leading 0. You have just reversed the day and month part in your formater

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no converting error and has nothing to do with missing leading 0. You have just reversed the day and month part in your formater. Just change

```
("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss") to ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
java.util.Date data = new java.util.Date();

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");

String dataString = formater.format(data);
dataString = dataString.replaceAll("-0", "-").replaceAll(":0", ":").replace(" 0", " ");
System.err.println("dataString = "+dataString);
```